# How to fix space between link and my text?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm a beginner in js programming and I am trying to make a discord bot(using discord.js) and am having some troubles!

How my script works: I want to do simple YouTube search, and after command key I write what I want to find!

For example : `!find skateboarding video`

[image: Screenshot]

- there I used(`!say`)

```
//("embed") 

googlesearch.setDescription(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${args.toString()})

**[using const googlesearch = new Discord.MessageEmbed();]**
```

```
   if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix))
   cmdLine = msg.content.slice(prefix.length, msg.content.length);
   cmd = cmdLine.slice(0,cmdLine.indexOf(' '));
   {
       
           if(cmd == 'инфо')
           {
              msg.channel.send(embed);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know discord.js exactly but if there is a space in args.toString() you can trim the beginning and ends with .trim() like this:

```
googlesearch.setDescription(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${args.toString().trim()})
```

doing this will still have spaces if there are two words. so in URLs when there are spaces, it's encoded with %20

javascript has an escape function that escapes the URL spaces and other symbols.

Example:

```
escape("@everyone hello world! #hashtag")
//outputs "@everyone%20hello%20world%21%20%23hashtag"
```

so this should work for your code

```
googlesearch.setDescription(escape(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${args.toString().trim()}`))
```

Edit: youtube querys separate spaces by `+` instead of %20, you can use the replaceAll() function instead of escape

```
googlesearch.setDescription(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${args.toString().trim().replaceAll(" ","+")}`)
```

Comment: Thanks very match.And last, how I can make + and non space in next words?
Like:red+beautiful+cat.

Comment: oh i see, so youtube querys are separated by +. in this case you can use replace all. I'll edit by answer

Comment: `googlesearch.setDescription(\`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${args.toString().trim().replaceAll(" ","+")}\`)`

Comment: says ```TypeError: args.toString(...).trim(...).replaceAll is not a function```

Comment: hmm it works for me. is it being tested on an old version of javascript or something?

Comment: instead of replace all try `args.toString().trim().replace(/ /g,"+")`

Comment: ТЁМА#8456 - write on discord(no, on new)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want to make a line break before the link, then you just have to type `\n` in front of the link in your code.
This should create a line break.
Hope I could help
ShadowLp174

Comment: I want make that fused, unite(Sorry for my English).(Unite link, and my text after command)

Comment: @Ruddien i think my solution answers your question

Comment: @Tony got it i think ;)

Comment: @Ruddien I don't want to be that guy but if you found any of the answers helpful can you give them an upvote or check or something? :)

Comment: Variant "${args.toString().trim().replace(/ /g,"+")}" works, thanks you a lot man!!!!